# Contact a recruiter, about job posting details, before or after lodging the application?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process

I read a job post today that is interesting for me.

The main issue is that the posting is for a 24-months long position, however due to personal circumstances outside my control. I'd like to request if they would even consider my application if I'd be only willing to take the job for 12 months.

I realized afterward that detail, so I have my cover letter and everything else ready to apply.

Are there norms on when to ask that?

- Do I ask them before lodging my application? And then apply only if a positive answer is given
- Do I put that in my application email along with my resume + cover letter?
- Do I apply, and then in a separate email, ask the question?

Comment: We do not know how that employer will react to your request. However, if they want someone for 24 months, they will be unlikely to accept you for 12 months. So the best solution is to ask them upfront if they will even take you in consideration for that job. Or you hide the information entirely, and just disappear after 12 months - which would be totally unprofessional, but beneficial for you temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide if removing yourself from consideration is what you want to do. If you know 100% that you can't take the job for more than 12 months, and you know the 24 months is a minimum requirement then finding out quickly makes sense.

But if you don't know 100% about staying longer than 12 months, then telling them now could eliminate you from consideration immediately. If you decide to apply, then you can ask for clarification regarding the 24 month requirement during the interview.

In general I wouldn't tell a place I was applying to that I can only stay a year. Why give them an excuse to reject my application. This case is slightly different because they mention 24 months in the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> The main issue is that the posting is for a 24-months long position,
> however due to personal circumstances outside my control. I'd like to
> request if they would even consider my application if I'd be only
> willing to take the job for 12 months.

Since you already know you don't meet the 24 month requirement, it makes sense to bring this up in your cover letter.

That will save both sides time, if the 24 month requirement cannot be waived.